# Firefox devtools: cannot commit scss file changes, file reverts 2 seconds after save

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am running Koala for my scss compiling. In FF devtools settings, I activated source-map files. Now I can alter the scss file in FF devtools-style editor, save the changes, Koala goes all green of joy, I see the the changes magically appear in the FF main window. All perfect up to this point. Now something strange happens: 2 seconds or so after the save, in devtools-style editor the scss file reverts to the state before save. The made changes in the FF main window persist, they don't vanish. Same with the scss file on the disk: The previously made changes are still there. Just not in the devtools-style editor. Here they are gone. Any Ideas? Thx!

Comment: here is a video of the problem:
https://vimeo.com/231002201

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Firefox. You should [file a bug in Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi), if one does not already exist.